# Python Numpy data Type error

Tags: python

Ok,  after hours of fun, I have to ask for help. I'm trying to take joined Oracle tables to a  ArcGIS Featureclass using python and numpy. I'm having trouble getting my SQL data, fieldnames, and numpy data type definition to work together.

This works..

```
numpyarr_out = np.array(datArray, np.dtype([('NAME', '|S50'), ('IDTYPE', '|S12'),('ORG_TYPE', '|S6'), ('FAC_TYPE', '|S50')]))
```

However it's hardcoded and my data changes based on the table, so  I grabbed a script that reads the Oracle tables and converts Oracle data types to numpy dtypes.

I can create an array of my data like this:

('OBJECTID', '|i8')
('ID', '|S35')
('IDTYPE', '|S100')
('NAME', '|S250')
('M_ADD1', '|S250')
('M_ADD2', '|S250')
('M_CITY', '|S100')
('M_STATE', '|S2')

However I have not idea how to format the following line to work.

```
numpyarr_out = np.array(datArray, np.dtype([myArr1]))
```

I get TypeError: data type not understood error.

I've tried adding quotes, (,[ and other characters in formatting my array to work.

Comment: What is the type of `myArr1`? A regular python list or a numpy array? In your example that works it is a list.

Comment: python list I did notice numpyarr_out = np.array(datArray, np.dtype(myArr1))  allows my featureclass to be created but without data, so it maybe past this error and on to the next.